# NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject and NSFileProtectionComplete/NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen

Tags: ios, nskeyedarchiver

Is it actually possible to call NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject and work with data protection API setting the file attribute to NSFileProtectionComplete or NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen ?

Comment: My current implementation uses 
+ (BOOL)archiveRootObject:(id)rootObject toFile:(NSString *)path
But I've not being able to find any information to see if that can work in conjunction of NSFileProtectionComplete

Comment: please let me know if my solution worked for you. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First attempt to write the object to the specific location, in this case docFile (this is set to the documents directory).  Then apply the file attributes to the docFile.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString* docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Somefile.plist"];
NSError* error;    

 if([NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:tempData toFile:docFile]) {

    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary
                                dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete
                                forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes     
                            ofItemAtPath:docFile  error: &error]) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
 else {
   NSLog@(%@", error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am on the road right now I'll try it as soon as I get home...thanks!

Comment: Yeah looks like it works ...it doesn't let me read the file after the device gets locked...thanks!